# display data by sql query for repeated values in same coloumn

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have table as follows:

```
site_id     customer    Date
------------------------------
xyz         Airtel      01/02/16
xyz         Idea        01/02/16
xyz         Aircel      01/02/16
abc         Aircel      01/02/16
abc         Airtel      01/02/16
abc         idea        01/02/16
pqr         idea        01/02/16
pqr         idea        01/02/16
pqr         Airtel      01/02/16
```

I want to display data for day on particular `site_id` how many customers are available.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Please tag the correct RDBMS. Additionally, please post the expected result!

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable WHERE site_id = YourSiteId AND date = YourDate`

Answer (score 0):

```
select site_id,customer,date
from table_name 
where site_id =input_site_id and date =input_date
```

Answer (score 0):

this will gives you the count of distinct customer by site by date

```
select site_id, date, count(distinct customer)
from   yourtable
group by site_id, date
```

if you want to know for a particular site & date, specify the condition in the WHERE clause. Example :

```
select site_id, date, count(distinct customer)
from   yourtable
where  site_id = 'xyz'
and    date    = '20160201'
group by site_id, date
```